# GitLab only user password authentication (no SSH)

Tags: git, authentication, gitlab

I installed GitLab successfully.

I want to create a user, with a username and password, so that he can push, pull from my repo, without the need for any SSH key whatsoever.

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `http(s)` push access instead of `SSH`.

[image: HTTPS mode]

1. When creating a new project, switch from `SSH` to `HTTPS`
2. The description for cloning the repository will change to `http(s)`
3. Push the project, shell will ask you for your GitLab credentials

Comment: The firewall was blocking us. Your answer made us retry-rethink again what was going on with HTTP. Thank you!